# Makefile tries to compile one of it's own rules as if it were a file

Tags: c, makefile

I have a simple makefile to compile some C code that uses OpenGL libraries, however, it appears to be interpreting one of it's own rules as a file to compile. The simplified version is as follows:

```
CC = gcc
COMPILEFLAGS = -Wall -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lm -c
LINKFLAGS = -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lm

castle: castle_link

run_castle:
    ./castle $(ARGS)

castle_link: castle_compile
    ${CC} -o castle castle.o ${LINKFLAGS}

castle_compile:
    ${CC} ${COMPILEFLAGS} castle.c

clean:
    rm *.o castle
```

Executing `make -n castle` yields the following:

```
gcc -Wall -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lm -c castle.c
gcc -o castle castle.o -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lm
gcc   castle.o castle_link   -o castle
```

And I cant understand *why* this happens. On this very same file there is another set of rules that follow precisely the same pattern, only changing file names, that work flawlessly.
(This only happens when executing the rule `make castle`, manually executing `castle_compile` and then `castle_link` does not cause that).

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Tangential issue: the `-lXYZ` options in the `COMPILEFLAGS` are not used because of the `-c` option and should be removed.

Comment: Can't reproduce, I only see the first two output lines.

Comment: Make rules must be named after the output files they produce, or (in case of `clean` and `castle`) marked as `.PHONY` to indicate that they produce none.

Comment: You should probably make the rule `run_castle` depend on the executable: `run_castle: castle`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you, I'm quite bad with remembering what goes where in regards to compilation flags. And, regarding your second comment, dependencies, it would appear

Comment: The problem reproduces with GNU Make 3.81 on MacOS (10.15.7 Catalina).

Comment: Run the output with `make -d -f makefile.bad castle > output.bad`.  Then with the other makefile that works as you want, run that too `make -d -f makefile.good program > output.good`.  Then compare the operations — which will be tedious.  There is, however, a critical difference.  We can't spot it for you because we don't have the other makefile to compare with.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Notable difference that I found, first being the good file and second the bad one:
`Removing child ... PID ... from chain.`
`  Successfully remade target file 'doll_link'.`
` Finished prerequisites of target file 'doll'.`
`Must remake target 'doll'.`
`Successfully remade target file 'doll'.`


`Removing child ... PID ... from chain.`
`  Successfully remade target file 'castle_link'.`
` Finished prerequisites of target file 'castle'.`
`Must remake target 'castle'.`
`gcc     castle.c castle_link   -o castle`

Comment: IMO, it would be better to make use of the built-in rules more.  Set `CFLAGS = -Wall`, `LDLIBS = -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lm`.  Write `castle: castle.o` with no command after it; remove `castle_link` and `castle_compile` altogether, and then the code works sanely — it compiles `castle.c` to `castle.o` and then links it with the libraries to make the executable.  However, that doesn't explain why you're seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This does indeed work sanely, thank you so very much.

Comment: Note that if you write just `castle:` without `castle.o` as a dependency, you get a single command executed: `gcc -Wall castle.c -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lm -o castle`, which is probably fine if you don't have a specific use for the object file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain what happened, you have a rule without a recipe:

```
castle: castle_link
```

which means that `make` will try to find an implicit rule for it. From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Rules.html#Multiple-Rules):

> If none of the explicit rules for a target has a recipe, then make searches for an applicable implicit rule to find one

And earlier in that page it says that prerequisites for targets are combined:

> One file can be the target of several rules. All the prerequisites mentioned in all the rules are merged into one list of prerequisites for the target.

The implicit rule that matches will be either:

```
%: %.o
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

if the `.o` file exists or:

```
%: %.c
    $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

if it doesn't. (`make -p` will print definitions of the implicit rules).

So the prerequisites for target `castle` will be:

- either castle.o castle_link
- or castle.c castle_link

And the `$^` variable in the recipe from the implicit rule will put them in the `cc` command to execute. Let's see with this simplified makefile:

```
castle: castle_link

castle_link: castle_compile
    $(CC) -o castle castle.o -lm

castle_compile:
    $(CC) -Wall -c castle.c
```

If we execute it on a clean directory (i.e. with no `castle.o`):

```
]$ make --debug=m castle
...
    Must remake target 'castle_compile'.
cc -Wall -c castle.c                                # This is our recipe, notice -Wall
    Successfully remade target file 'castle_compile'.
  Must remake target 'castle_link'.
cc -o castle castle.o -lm                           # This is our reicpe, notice -lm
  Successfully remade target file 'castle_link'.
Must remake target 'castle'.
cc     castle.c castle_link   -o castle             # This is implicit rule with castle.c
cc: error: castle_link: No such file or directory
```

Now that `castle.o` was created, we execute it again:

```
]$ make --debug=m castle
...
    Must remake target 'castle_compile'.
cc -Wall -c castle.c                                # This is our recipe, notice -Wall
    Successfully remade target file 'castle_compile'.
  Must remake target 'castle_link'.
cc -o castle castle.o -lm                           # This is our recipe, notice -lm
  Successfully remade target file 'castle_link'.
 Prerequisite 'castle_link' of target 'castle' does not exist.
Must remake target 'castle'.
cc   castle.o castle_link   -o castle               # This is implicit rule with castle.o
cc: error: castle_link: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, in the first invocation it was "cc castle.c castle_link -o castle" and in the second it was "cc castle.o castle_link -o castle".

Don't ask me why only the second invocation printed "Prerequisite 'castle_link' of target 'castle' does not exist." :-)

Comment: Well, I'd never think of something like that being the root cause, thank you very much for your answer.